# VueJs - Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, conditional-rendering

Hello I'm doing a dropdown in my website and I'm really new in Vue. I'm using conditional rendering for display some cards. Something like: Cars, Motos, Bikes. When i click on Cars there is a dropdown and i get a list of cars, same on others.

```
                        <h2 class="text-center my-font text-light"><button v-on:click="toggle = !toggle" class="badge badge-danger menu-label-size w-50">Cars</button></h2> 
                        <div v-if="toggle" class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="cards-item text-center ">
                              <div v-for="item in cars" ::key="item.id" class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                                  <img :src="'./images/cars/img' + item.img + '.png'" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="item.name">
                                  <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
                                    <h4 class="card-title my-font">{{ item.name }}</h4>
                                    <p class="badge-danger font-weight-bold">{{ item.price }}</p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <h2 class="text-center my-font text-light"><button v-on:click="toggle = !toggle" class="badge badge-danger menu-label-size w-50">Motos</button></h2> 
                        <div v-if="toggle" class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="cards-item text-center">
                              <div v-for="item in motos" ::key="item.id" class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                                  <img :src="'./images/motos/img' + item.img + '.png'" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="item.name">
                                  <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
                                    <h4 class="card-title my-font">{{ item.name }}</h4>
                                    <p class="badge-danger font-weight-bold">{{ item.price }}</p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <h2 class="text-center my-font text-light"><button v-on:click="toggle = !toggle" class="badge badge-danger menu-label-size w-50">Bikes</button></h2> 
                        <div v-if="toggle" class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="cards-item text-center">
                              <div v-for="item in bikes" ::key="item.id" class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                                  <img :src="'./images/bikes/img' + item.img + '.png'" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="item.name">
                                  <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
                                    <h4 class="card-title my-font">{{ item.name }}</h4>
                                    <p class="badge-danger font-weight-bold">{{ item.price }}</p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

My script:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    show: false,
    cars: [{data}],
    motos: [{data}],
    bikes: [{data}],
},
})
```

But when i click on Motos it only closes Cars. How to make it dynamic? Like if i press Motos then it opens and Cars closes, same for Bikes

Comment: I would use this algorithm: create a variable called `activeSelection = null;` when you click on e.g. cars it will assign `cars` to `activeSelection` variable. and create if statement check to close / open lists this way: `activeSelection === 'cars'` - for cars. Use similar approach for other types. To save some bytes, you can create constants with numbers e.g. cars variable will be `0`, motos `1`, and use these constants to assign `activeSelection` variable to existing constants and do a check using the same constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge your vehicles data in mounted hook, then loop thru items:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: () => ({
    items: [],
    expanded: null,
    cars: [{img: '', name: 'car1', price: 5}, {img: '', name: 'car2', price: 6}, {img: '', name: 'car3', price: 8}],
    motors: [{img: '', name: 'motor1', price: 5}, {img: '', name: 'motor2', price: 6}, {img: '', name: 'motor3', price: 8}],
    bikes: [{img: '', name: 'bike1', price: 5}, {img: '', name: 'bike2', price: 6}, {img: '', name: 'bike3', price: 8}]
  }),
  methods: {
    expand(idx) {
      this.expanded = this.expanded === idx ?  null : idx
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const car = {title: 'Cars', products: this.cars}
    const motor = {title: 'Motors', products: this.motors}
    const bike = {title: 'Bikes', products: this.bikes}
    this.items = [car, motor, bike]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="demo" class="d-flex">
  <div v-for="(group, index) in items" :key="index">
    <h2 class="text-center my-font text-light">
      <button @click="expand(group)" class="badge badge-danger menu-label-">{{ group.title }}</button>
    </h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="cards-item text-center">
          <div v-if="expanded === group">
            <div v-for="(item, idx) in group.products" :key="idx" class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
              <img :src="'./images/motos/img' + item.img + '.png'" class="card-img-top img-fluid" :alt="item.name">
              <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
                <h4 class="card-title my-font">{{ item.name }}</h4>
                <p class="badge-danger font-weight-bold">{{ item.price }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is the behaviour i was looking for.. but i can't adapt it to my code, when i put data function i get error. I have static data for cars,motos,bikes and i loop them to show in html. I edited the whole code of my question for be more specific

Comment: @shaddark hey mate, check again, I updated my answer.